# source from array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am a newbe in HTML and JavaScript. I have a short code that embeds several audio files. I am using a loop, and I want to use strings from an ARRAY as Source for the wav files (instead for "file1.wav". Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <body>
    <p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    var AudioFiles = [
    "file1.wav",
    "file2.wav",
    "file3.wav",
    ];

    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + `
          <audio controls>
            <source src="file1.wav"; type="audio/wav">
          </audio>
      `
    };
</script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *string interpolation* and array index lookup for this, as it seems you're using ES6.

```
<script>
    var AudioFiles = [
    "file1.wav",
    "file2.wav",
    "file3.wav",
    ];

    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + `
          <audio controls>
            <source src="${AudioFiles[i]}"; type="audio/wav">
          </audio>
      `
    };
</script>
```

However, there are some issues I'd point out:

Firstly we don't tend to name our variables with an initial capital letter by convention. (So use `audioFiles` instead of `AudioFiles`. Capital letters are reserved for classes and constructors, usually.

Secondly, this might not be the best way to append elements into the DOM. 
Take a look at the `appendChild` function: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

Thirdly, we can use the function `forEach` to do a similar thing without manually using a counter ourselves, which is better because it's more declarative, and less prone to error:

```
<script>
    var audioFiles = [
      "file1.wav",
      "file2.wav",
      "file3.wav",
    ];

    audioFiles.forEach(function(item) {
      document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + `
          <audio controls>
            <source src="${item}"; type="audio/wav">
          </audio>
      `
    });
</script>
```

This will take each item in `audioFiles` and pass it into the *iterator* function as `item`.

However, we can do even better than this...

```
<script>
    var audioFiles = [
      "file1.wav",
      "file2.wav",
      "file3.wav",
    ];

    document.body.innerHTML =
      document.body.innerHTML +
        audioFiles.map(function(item) {
         return `
          <audio controls>
            <source src="${item}"; type="audio/wav">
          </audio>
      `}).join();
</script>
```

That way we repeat ourselves less, so again there's less to go wrong.

The map function goes over an array and turns it into another array, the result of the *iterator function*.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the array index inside the loop

```
var AudioFiles = [
"file1.wav",
"file2.wav",
"file3.wav",
];

for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML +'<audio controls><source src="'+AudioFiles[i]+'"; type="audio/wav"></audio>'
};
```

Comment: Add a space between audio and controls

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using template literals you can use this syntax: `${variable}` to embed outside variables in your string.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + `
      <audio controls>
        <source src="${AudioFiles[i]}"; type="audio/wav">
      </audio>
  `
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const audioFiles = ["file1.wav", "file2.wav", "file3.wav"]; //list all file paths
const html = audioFiles.map(audio => {
    return ` 
    <audio controls>
      <source src="${audio}"; type="audio/wav">
    </audio>`;
}).join(""); /*prepare html to update - remember to join(""),
because map outputs an array*/
document.body.innerHTML += html;
```

This method updates the DOM only once.